Why is the solution to a harmonic equation split into two classes when one class suffices?
If we solve $\sin(x) = 0$, we arrive at $$x = n \pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
When I do (Reduce also returns the same)
  Solve[Sin[x] == 0, {x}, Reals]

The result is
$$\{\{x\to \fbox{$2 \pi  c_1\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\},\{x\to \fbox{$2 \pi  c_1+\pi \text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\}\}$$
Why is that result so convoluted? While it certainly is workable, it is also quite ugly. Any way to make it look like the above?
For the record, Wolfram Alpha returns that much more succinct result.
Using MMA 14.1, Windows 10, x86.

Exactly the same question without an answer: Simplify solution of trigonometric equation.

How did I miss that as I did search for it? A shame no one is answering this as I think it could be considered a bug.

Why do you think n Pi is a better answer than zero, or 2 n Pi for that matter.  M can't read your mind.  A bug is giving an incorrect answer.

And another one: Reduce[Sin[x]==0,x] splitting odd and even multiples of Pi. And another one looking for a solution: How to combine multiple ConditionalExpressions?.

@BillWatts: Because the first result is what you derive manually.

Someone else might derive zero manually.  Derive?,  I think you mean memorize.

It is a periodic function and can be plotted to see the pattern and then verified for each value. No need to memorize anything.
